# How to calculate time difference in R?

Tags: r

I have limited ability in R, so please bear with me.

I have a data set of 50000 rows. There are two time formats, as follows:

```
A       B       C              D
1050101 0080116 10501010001    10501011328
1050101 0400915 10501010005    10501011332
1050101 0930205 10501010008    10501010014
1050101 0290116 10501010014    10501010243
1050101 0961004 10501010017    10501010100
```

The time format of the first two columns (A&B) are yyymmdd, and the time format of the last two columns(C&D) are yyymmddhhmm. I'd like to calculate the time difference (in years) between A and B column. And also the time difference (in minutes) between C and D columns. 
Please note the year 105 plus 1911 equals 2016, which is this year. I don't know whether this information helps or not. 
I've checked the website but couldn't find the similar answers to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"A       B       C              D
1050101 0080116 10501010001    10501011328
1050101 0400915 10501010005    10501011332
1050101 0930205 10501010008    10501010014
1050101 0290116 10501010014    10501010243
1050101 0961004 10501010017    10501010100")

as.Date(as.character(d$A+1911e4), "%Y%m%d")
as.POSIXct(as.character(d$C+1911e8), format="%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.